# can't print specific printer - jasper report

Tags: java, printing, jasper-reports

I have two printers connect to my PC (COM PORT 3 AND 4)
(names : Printer_aa1, Printer_bb2)

I want to select and print my jasper document by this printer name or any index ( like 0 and 1)

my code only print from default printer. i cant select any printer.
Please help me to solve this.

thank you

```
public void printReciept_non(int printer) {

    String reportSource = "receipt_non.jrxml"; //sale_report_new

    Map<String, Object> parameter = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameter.put("total_amount", priceWithDecimal(totalAmount));
    parameter.put("order_code", lbl_orderNo.getText());
    parameter.put("table_no", tableNo);
    parameter.put("IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION", true);

    Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US");
    parameter.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, locale);

    try {
        JasperReport js = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);
        JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(js, parameter, new check().getConn());

        JasperPrintManager.printReport(jp, false);

        PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
        int selectedService = printer;
        PrintService[] printService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);

        try {
            printerJob.setPrintService(printService[selectedService]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        printRequestAttributeSet.add(MediaSizeName.NA_LETTER);
        printRequestAttributeSet.add(new Copies(0));
        JRPrintServiceExporter exporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter();
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jp);

        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_SERVICE, services[selectedService]);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_SERVICE_ATTRIBUTE_SET, services[selectedService].getAttributes());
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_SET, printRequestAttributeSet);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PAGE_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PRINT_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
        exporter.exportReport();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```